# What mechanism determines what is featured in the Community Bulltin on the main page?

Tags: support, feature-request, request

What mechanism determines which meta posts or blog articles are featured in the Community Bulltin on the main page?

Concerning blog articles, I would guess that the newest ones are featured.

But the mechanisms to determine which meta question is featured, is completely unclear to me. Is it automatically decided by criteria that describe the activity and popularity of the meta question for example, such as votes, views, date of posting, etc?

Or is it the moderators of our site who determine "by hand" which meta question is featured in the community bulltin?

I am wondering about this because currently, the meta post dedicated to [reevaluate the book policy](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4697/2751) is featured in the Community Bulltin, whereas the meta post requesting to [burnicate](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4699/2751) the popular-science tag does not appear in the Community Bulltin on the main page.

The date of posting of both of these two quite recent meta questions differes only by a few hours, and both of them are very important for the community and concern important political issues of Physics SE.

I think all meta question looking for community input to find consensus about important site political issues should be featured in the Community Bulltin, such that the people who are mostly active on the main page and dont click meta too often, have a better chance to take note of them too.

So, if the featuring of meta questions in the Community Bulltin can be done "by hand" by an appropriate site moderator action, can the burnicate request of the popular science tag be featured there too? I request featuring this meta question too there.

The burnicate request is very important for everybody too and has a huge impact on how people will be able to use the site in the future, and it has the potential to annihilate the by the community appreciated level proposel. It is much more important and has a higher impact on the community than for example the currently featured regulating user names or the miner edit post.

Comment: miner edit? Why would a miner edit the post ?

Comment: Hi @Dimension10, I was talking about [this](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/4702/2751) question being listed in the Community Bulltin, instead of the two much more important current political meta discussions.

Comment: No, I meant this:    http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coal_mining

Comment: @Dimension10: As in, "currently featured regulating user names or the ***miner*** edit post.".

Comment: [meta.se]: [What criteria are used to select the links that appear in the community bulletin sidebar block?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/130621) (Maybe other information [in the corresponding tag-info](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/community-bulletin/info) might be of interest, too.)

Answer (score 1):

It's not by hand, it depends on the vote score and other things.

Mods can add community events to the bulletin and can mark meta posts as featured if necessary, but we don't control the automatically shown stuff.

I don't mind marking the book request post as [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) (would have to discuss that with other mods), as it could be a rather major policy change but the burninate request isn't something that really qualifies to be featured.

Comment: I disagree with the burnicate request not being something that qualifies to be featured. It is very important too and has a huge impact on how people will be able to use the site in the future, and it has the potential to annihilate the by the community appreciated level proposel, which has been featured by the way. It is much more important and has a higher impact on the community than for example the currently featured Regulating user names or the miner edit post. So could you not at the feature tag to both, the book post and the burnicate request?

Comment: Or could you at least discuss featuring the burnicate request with other mods too, to assess how they see it?

Comment: @Dilaton Sure, they are free to do it (we may discuss it after the rest have seen this meta post). But in general tag burninations (aside from _mass_ tag burninations) aren't featured, but major policy changes are.

Comment: Thanks @Manishearth. This particular burnicate request concerning popular science is not just about getting rid of an unimportant/obscure/minor/or douplicate tag where nobody has a strong opinion as usually. The popular science issue is politically loaded and highly controversial, so it would be good if it can be featered too on the main page ... Anyway, as you said we will see, this meta post is quite new and everybody has to see it first.

Comment: I agree with Manishearth, the tag burninate request shouldn't be featured.