# Everyday physics tag?

Tags: feature-request, tags

In the question [why popcorns become soft after popping](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/112015/) the tag `popcorn` was suggested. I think it would be nice to have a more general `everyday physics`, or a better name that you could come up with, to collect the explanations of everyday phenomena.

Note that this is not `popular-science`, that [was](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4699/) not [liked](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4295/) by the community. It is not "explain in simple words what QFT is".

Would it be interesting? In the interest of archives, if approved, should we go through old questions and re-tag them?

Comment: On a related note we do have [home-experiment](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/home-experiment), but that is not exactly the same thing as it presumes an activity rather than just an explanation.

Comment: a [popcorn] tag, however is far to specific to be useful, and I have removed it.

Comment: @dmckee there was some discussion in the comments about it, now removed. I anyway agree is way too specific.

Answer (score 5):

We already have such a tag, [everyday-life](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/everyday-life). I personally don't think it's all that useful, but in any case it does exist and I guess this is the sort of thing it was meant for.

Comment: I totally missed it, it is being underused. Should then be encouraging its usage?

Comment: I don't think so. As I said, I don't believe any tag with this meaning should exist on the site at all; it doesn't say anything about what kind of physics the question is about. But that's just me.

Answer (score 4):

I was the one who made the comment about adding a "popcorn" tag. I was actually making a joke when I said it; the point of the humor was to highlight the ridiculousness of making a tag for such a specific concept, but apparently the OP thought I was being serious.

I would say "garbage in, garbage out", but considering that I am a dumpster, that would probably be hypocritical.

Comment: You must have not be the only one, as you need 1k rep to create it... Anyway, thanks for the clarification, I just vaguely recalled it.